# How to update FreeBSD without freebsd-update when the source cannot be compiled?

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, arm64

I run FreeBSD on a Raspberry Pi 3.  This computer is permanently installed in a server room I do not have easy access to.  Once FreeBSD 12 comes out, I want to update the computer to the new system release.  According to the handbook, there are two ways to do so:

1. use **freebsd-update**(8) to do a binary update
2. compile and install FreeBSD from the source tree

Option (1) is unavailable as arm64 is not a tier 1 platform.  Previously I went with option (2), but ever since LLVM was updated to 6.0, the system does not have enough RAM to compile FreeBSD.  Adding more swap interestingly did not help very much.  Compiling LLVM was always the most annoying part of the compilation process and now it's what breaks option (2) entirely.

What other options do I have to update the system?  Previously I tried the following ways:

- Download the tar balls of the FreeBSD 12 distribution and unpack them over the running system.  While this seems to have worked, it was a huge pain in the ass to make sure no configuration was overwritten and I have no way to ensure that no old files remain.
- Compile the source tree on a different system, transplant it over and install that.  As I do not have another arm64 computer I tried to cross-compile from amd64 FreeBSD.  Transplanting this source tree didn't seem to work but I don't remember what the problem was.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe a solution can be the PkgBase (https://wiki.freebsd.org/PkgBase) - it seems it should work (https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/freebsd-update-on-raspberry-pi.57911/#post-330628).

Comment: @uzsolt I thought so too, but then the description of package base begins with how to make these packages yourself—if I could do so, I could also build the system from source.

Comment: But maybe the next update doesn't need building :)

Comment: @uzsolt I cannot even build one update!  That's the whole damn problem.  Also, I don't really get why I'd ever stop needing to build.  It's not like anybody else builds these packages for me.

Comment: Cross-compiling on a system with more RAM is likely the best fix. You'll need to be a whole lot more specific about the issues you have with that to get help there.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol Again: I want to avoid having to build FreeBSD from source.  Is there a way to do so?

Comment: If someone else does the builds and you download them. You made it sound like that's not an option.

Comment: @CupcakeProtocol Do you know any ready-made builds I can download?  That would solve my entire problem.

Comment: Sorry, no, I don't.

Comment: You should ask such questions on the mailing lists or irc channels where the FreeBSD devs hang out.

Comment: @Rob I thought that others might profit more from an answer on such a slightly less ephemeral medium.

Comment: But you're not getting an answer. It's perfectly alright to find the answer there and post it here as an answer.